# Can a mathematical difference not also imply a disjunction?

Tags: logic

Is there a disjunction for every difference? E.g. 2-1=1 which implies a disjunction e.g. the sets 1 and 2 are disjunct. So can there not be any difference that not also implies a disjunction?

Comment: In one of the common ways to define the natural numbers, $1$ and $2$ are not disjoint (was that what you meant by disjunct?)

Comment: Yes, I thought 1 and 2 were "disjoint sets" like 0 and 1 are disjunct probabilities.

Comment: If we think of numbers as sets (either in the standard way or some other way,) how does the equation $2-1=1$ imply that 1 and 2 are disjoint?  What is your set-theoretic interpretation of subtraction?  (Note that if $2-1$ means the "set difference" $2 \setminus 1$, then $2-1=1$ is false regardless of your set-theoretic definition of $1$ and $2$.)  Also, beware that (rather confusingly) the meanings of "disjunction" and "disjoint" are totally different in mathematical logic.

Comment: Thank you. Are the meanings of "disjunction" =set S1 and "disjoint" = set S2 disjunct meanings or disjoint meanings or neither? How can I know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim that numbers are sets is controversial; if they are not sets, talk of them being ‘disjoint’ doesn't make sense.

If one does identify numbers with sets, the best-known way of doing so is von Neumann's, on which each number is the set of its predecessors, so that in particular $0=∅$, $1=\{∅\}$ and $2=\{∅,\{∅\}\}$.  On this approach, 1 and 2 are not disjoint, in fact $1⊂2$.  And in general $x⊂y$ whenever $x≤y$.

Comment: I understand. It's like counting empty sets(?) Any other techniques where numbers are disjoint or disjunct and a number actually has a complement? The empty set has a complement which is the universe (?)